# Selenium cookie for subdomain

Tags: django, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I'm setting up some functional tests for a django site which redirects users to dashboard.appname.com when they visit appname.com when they're already logged in.

In order to allow this in the test infrastructure, I need to add a cookie to the browser with .appname.com as the domain.

I do this with

```
self.browser.add_cookie(dict(
    name=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
    domain='.appname.com',
    value=session_key,
    path='/',
))
```

This all works fine when I use the Chrome webdriver but if I use the Firefox webdriver, I get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: InvalidCookieDomainError is not defined
```

which I *think* means that it won't allow a wildcard subdomain like this. But I need to use the wildcard in order to get the dashboard.appname.com to work.

Given that the Chrome webdriver works, I suspect that it's geckodriver that's broken but I'm not 100% sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an open issue in the firefox driver :(
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1025